# Sync Project with Gradle Files

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've recently downloaded the Android Studio Bundle v0.3.2 for Windows, and now trying to complete the Google Maps Android API tutorial. There is a step which require to **Click Sync Project with Gradle Files**. I can't seem to find this button anywhere in Android Studio. Just in case here is a link of the Google Maps tutorial: [Set Up Google Play Services SDK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Sync Project with Gradle` option was added in Android Studio [0.4.0](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio040released) and Android Studio is now on version [0.4.2](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio042released) - make sure to check for updates within Android Studio (on Windows, it is the `Help` menu, then `Check for update...`)

Comment: I've tried it but it says no update available. I've checked the **About ADT** windows and the build version is v22.3.0-887826. How do i check the version of Android Studio? Is this the latest?

Comment: ADT is the Eclipse plugin and totally different from [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html). Are you sure you've downloaded Android Studio and not the ADT bundle?

Comment: You were right, I've downloaded the Android Studio v0.4.2 and installed it and now i can see the button. Thank you!

PS:Yes i think i had Android Studio and not the ADT Bundle. Either way I have downloaded the new version and installed it. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful shortcut **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **A**, after which a window appears and you can type some command that you would like IntelliJ to run. Just type "sync" in there and it will find that command **Sync Project with Gradle Files**, even if it's not visible in the menu.